# CSS: inner div overlapping

Tags: html, css

I need to create so-called "label" inside container div. The label should appear in the top - left corner and should look like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/k6G27/). The obvious way is to shift the inner div a bit so that a part of it would be overlapped by the container. But the inner div outside the container is still [visible](http://jsfiddle.net/Gxxbg/).

How do I achieve this effect without "bruteforcing"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are looking but would adding `overflow:hidden` to the outer div be what you are looking for?

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gxxbg/1/)***

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` on the outer will do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/Gxxbg/2/